# ios json parse with afnetworking

Tags: php, ios, json

hi :) im having problem with word with accent when i parse json data 
it was first in the web service but i fixed it

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/json; charset=utf-8');
include('settings.php');
mysql_connect($host,$user,$password);
mysql_select_db($base);

mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');

$req = "select * from patient";
$sql=mysql_query($req);
$nn=mysql_num_rows($sql);

$items = array("items" => NULL);

while ($data=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $items["items"][] = array(
        "id_patient" => $data['id_patient'],
        "nom" => $data['nom'],
        "prenom" => $data['prenom'],
        "Sexe" => $data['Sexe'],
        "date_de_naissance" => $data['date_de_naissance'],
        "lieu_de_naissance" => $data['lieu_de_naissance'],
        "adresse" =>$data['adresse'],
        "latitude" => $data['latitude'],
        "longitude" => $data['longitude'],
        "telephone" => $data['telephone'],
        "email" => $data['email'],
        "situation_familiale" => $data['situation_familiale'],
        "profession" => $data['profession'],
        "numero_securite_sociale" => $data['numero_securite_sociale'],
        "taille" => $data['taille'],
        "poids" => $data['poids'],
        "situation_familiale" => $data['situation_familiale'],
        "groupe_sanguin" => $data['groupe_sanguin'],
        "allergies" =>$data['allergies'],
        "antecedents_chirurgicaux" => $data['antecedents_chirurgicaux'],
        "antecedents_medicaux" => $data['antecedents_medicaux'],
        "antecedents_familiaux" => $data['antecedents_familiaux'],
                );
}   
    echo json_encode($items,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

?>

```
in the server its good im getting it fine 

 "allergies":poussiére
```

but when i parse it with afnetworking im getting   allergies = "poussi\U00e9re";

can anyone help me :) thx

Comment: Only when you log the contents or also when you display it on screen?

Comment: it's only in the log i didn't try to display it yet

Comment: Try to display it, should be fine

Comment: can u add ur api request

Answer (score 0):

In your request method add this

```
[AFJSONRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:
                        [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/json"]];
```